# Miktex unable to install package "placeins"

Tags: packages, installing, placeins

Trying to install placeins, doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{placeins}

\begin{document}
Text
\end{document}
```

In the log of TeXstudio, it reads

```
Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "test".tex

Unfortunately, the package placeins could not be installed. Please check the log file: C:\Users\cr\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\pdflatex.log
```

In the specified file, it reads

```
2019-11-13 11:26:42,373+0100 INFO  pdflatex - starting with command line: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode test.tex
2019-11-13 11:26:42,380+0100 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2019-11-13 11:26:42,381+0100 INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2019-11-13 11:26:42,513+0100 INFO  pdflatex - installing package placeins triggered by tex/latex/placeins\placeins.sty
2019-11-13 11:26:45,304+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: starting package maintenance...
2019-11-13 11:26:45,306+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"
2019-11-13 11:26:45,306+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: package repository: http://ftp.rrze.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2019-11-13 11:26:45,663+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: package repository digest: 6f45c497f2c9e9dd7da60de60809775d
2019-11-13 11:26:45,691+0100 FATAL pdflatex - The requested package is unknown.
2019-11-13 11:26:45,691+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: ="name="placeins""
2019-11-13 11:26:45,691+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\PackageDataStore.cpp
2019-11-13 11:26:45,691+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 394
2019-11-13 11:26:45,845+0100 INFO  pdflatex - finishing with exit code 1
```

**EDIT:**
When I try to open the MiKTeX console manually, I get this little message at the bottom right of the screen:
[image]

How can this be resolved?

Comment: Very strange… Maybe, from MiKTeX console, choose the  `Tasks -> Update package database`  first, then ask to install the package.

Comment: thanks for your message. check out the edit i made :)

Comment: You can't launch the console (administrator and user)?

Comment: yes, that goes for both

Comment: I'm afraid there's a problem with your installation – unless you're trying to launch the console before the compiler has stopped.